# How do I dynamically update text on a “shared” webpage based on which link is pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of workshop dates on my home page with links that direct users to the registration form/ page.

Everything on the registration page is static with the exception of the “date” and “location”.

How do I pass info from the home page to the registration page after the user clicks on the  link?

Guessing I have to assign some values to the links? Not sure how.

HTML for the Links on my home page:

```
<div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
      <h5>21-22</h5>
      <medium class="text-muted">JUN</medium>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-11">
      <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
        <h5 class="mb-1">INSPIRED</h5>
        <a href="sampleurl.com/registrationform">
        <h6> register <i class="bi-arrow-right"></i> </h6>
        </a> </div>
      <p class="mb-1">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
      <hr/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: There are many ways of getting data from one page to another. You can post the data in a form, send it on the querystring (url), store it in a cookie, store it in localStorage. Which one you should use really depends on your needs as none of them are particularly challenging to implement.

Comment: @LeeTaylor do you mind showing me an example of how that might work in my context? I've updated my post with the code snippet I'm using on my home page (index.html) which directs to the registration page. 

As for the 'querystring' you mention, how do I find that/ create one? For context, I'm running these pages on Confluence. I've tried simply using the destination URL for the registration page but that didn't work since I don't think just any url can accept post requests.

Comment: Done. Please see my answer and accept/vote accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the following code and hosting it on codepen. Please **do not** edit this to be a snippet as the snippets do not allow use of the queryString!

**HTML:**

```
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="0" selected>-- Please Choose -- </option>
  <option value="1">Apple</option>
  <option value="2">Banana</option>
  <option value="3">Carrot</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
// Get the values from the queryString in a convenient way.
let qs = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

// Extract the value we're interested in
let value = qs.get("value");

// Update our dropdown to represent the value we passed along
let select = document.getElementById("dropdown");
select.value = value;
```

If you run the below, the dropdown will select "Apple":

> https://codepen.io/MrLeeTaylor/pen/JjpQvjW?value=1

If you run the below, the dropdown will select "Carrot":

> https://codepen.io/MrLeeTaylor/pen/JjpQvjW?value=3

You will see that the url holds values on the querystring (the part after the ?). This allows us to send values to another page. If you want to send more than one you would do so like this:

> `?value=3&otherValue=hello`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It can be applied with multiple ways as needed, you can add query parameters to your link.
ex:

{{ url }}?key=value&key2=value2

You can also use local storage or session storage, it depends on your needs.

Comment: Pretty new to coding, could you show me how that might look? I've updated my post to include the code snippet I'm using in my home page index.html file.